# Extract data from yahoo finance using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, extract, yahoo-finance

Hi I need help with this code I'm trying to extract data from this page https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ADM.L/balance-sheet?p=ADM.L ,
but the problem is page is by default set to annual but I need quarterly values of total assets and total liabilities.

This code runs but most of the time it is picking annual values. Please suggest something what can I do.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
'
Dim ie As Object
Set Rng = Range("A2:A50")
Set Row = Range(Rng.Offset(1, 0), Rng.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
'.Visible = False
For Each Row In Rng
.navigate "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & Range("A" & Row.Row).Value & "/balance-sheet?p=" & Range("A" & Row.Row).Value
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
While ie.readyState <> 4
Wend

Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = ie.document

doc.getElementsByClassName("P(0px) M(0px) C($actionBlue) Bd(0px) O(n)")(2).Click

Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Range("D" & Row.Row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("Fw(b) Fz(s) Ta(end)")(4).innerText
Range("E" & Row.Row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("Fw(b) Fz(s) Ta(end)")(12).innerText
Range("F" & Row.Row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("C($gray) Ta(end)")(0).innerText


Next Row
End With
ie.Quit
'
End Sub
```

Comment: *Please suggest something what can I do.* - You can use IE to choose the quarterly data before writing the elements to your worksheet.

Comment: I did but it is not working always....mostly it is picking up the quarter data

Comment: I thought you wanted it to pick up the quarter data?

Comment: Assuming this line: `doc.getElementsByClassName("P(0px) M(0px) C($actionBlue) Bd(0px) O(n)")(2).Click` is what clicks the link for quarterly data, place a pause the VBA code for a few seconds to allow the events to catch up. I've found I had to do this often when automating IE with VBA.

Comment: I have already put a pause
can you please check by running it yourself
here are the tickers for url
III.L ,
ABF.L, 
ADM.L

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good start for you to get going.

```
Sub DownloadData()

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")


With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ADM.L/balance-sheet?p=ADM.L"

' Wait for the page to fully load; you can't do anything if the page is not fully loaded
Do While .Busy Or _
    .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop


Set e = ie.Document.GetElementsByClassName("Fz(s) Fw(500) D(ib) Pend(15px) H(18px) C($finDarkLink):h Mend(15px)")(1)
e.Click

    ' Wait for the page to fully load; you can't do anything if the page is not fully loaded
    Do While .Busy Or _
        .readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

End With

End Sub
```

Basically, 'Annual' is the default and you have to click the 'Quarterly' link, to get the quarterly data displayed.  I believe yahoo used to have 2 different URLs for Annual and Quarterly.  Now, apparently, they give you 2 links to click to toggle back and forth between the 2 frequencies of financial statements.

Answer (score 0):

Do find below on the code fix.  Do take note that Yahoo has updated the classname i.e. from "P(0px) M(0px) C($actionBlue) Bd(0px) O(n)" ==> "P(0px) M(0px) C($c-fuji-blue-1-b) Bd(0px) O(n)".

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim ie As Object
    Set Rng = Range("A2:A50")
    Set row = Range(Rng.Offset(1, 0), Rng.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        For Each row In Rng
            .navigate "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & Range("A" & row.row).Value & "/balance-sheet?p=" & Range("A" & row.row).Value

            While ie.readyState <> 4
            Wend

            Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

            Dim doc As HTMLDocument
            Set doc = ie.document

            Set element = doc.getElementsByClassName("P(0px) M(0px) C($c-fuji-blue-1-b) Bd(0px) O(n)")(2)
            element.Click

            Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

            Range("D" & row.row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("Fw(b) Fz(s) Ta(end)")(4).innerText
            Range("E" & row.row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("Fw(b) Fz(s) Ta(end)")(12).innerText
            Range("F" & row.row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("C($gray) Ta(end)")(0).innerText
        Next row
    End With
    ie.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to extract Quarterly data from Yahoo using VBA.
Annual data can be extracted, but not quarterly.